# What is the logic behind the output of this program?

Tags: c, io

```
  #include  <stdio.h>
  int main ()
  {
    int i=10;
    int x=printf("%d ",i);
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
  }
```

Output of the above code is "10 3"

Comment: What is the return value from `printf`?

Comment: Check the manual for printf, i.e. what is returned. There are several place you can read that, e.g. here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html **RETURN VALUE:** Upon successful return, these functions return the number of
       characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to
       strings).

Answer (score 1):

It prints the first string ( `i` as a decimal is part of it) and then prints the return value of `printf` from the first call.

Perhaps if you check out `printf` documentation you will understand why the second output isn't 2.

Comment: "...why the second output isn't 2." Hmm... I don't see why one would ever expect 2 as output. Perhaps 4 but not 2.

Comment: You'd be surprised at how many people don't really look at code and instead make assumptions on what they read as they skim over it. Its one of the main sources of bugs after all. I suspect that the OP thinks that the output should be "10 2"